# Permanent link to all products/collection

Tags: shopify

Here is another newby shopify "double" question.
I have a "permanent" link on my sidebar:

```
 <li class="{% if page_url  == 
"/collections/all" %}active{% endif %}">
<a href="/collections/all">{{collection.title}}</a>
</li>
```

Problem here is that whan we are at the all products page the link is displays correctly "ALL PRODUCTS". When we go to a particular colelction of course {{collection.title}} displays corresponding collection name. So the question is how to access the title of "all collections" ?

And the second question is : how to highlight it? I'm trying this (as shown above):

```
{% if page_url  == 
"/collections/all" %}active{% endif %}">
```

But it does not work on all collection/products .

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`{{ shop.url }}` will return the full URL of a shop. You can do something like the following:

```
<li class="{% if page_url  == "/collections/all" %}active{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ shop.url }}/collections/all">{{collection.title}}</a>
</li>
```

[Here](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/shop#shop-url) you can see the Shopify Doc.

Comment: The link /collections/all works well on all pages. It's collection.title that outputs the title of the curent collection you are in, while the link still (as it should) points to "all collections".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is something like this:

```html
<li class="{% if collection.handle  == "all" %}active{% endif %}">
  <a href="/collections/all">{{collections.all.title}}</a>
</li>
```

You can use the global [`collections`](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects#global-objects) object to access the title of the "all" collection regardless of which page you're on.

To add the "active" class when the URL is /collections/all, check the current collection's [handle](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/handle).

Comment: Isn't `collections.all.title` blank?

Comment: Just tested. Yep, it's blank :( Adding class active works well though.

Comment: Hmm, `collections.all.title` returns "Products" for me. It's not a problem, you can create a [smart collection with handle "all"](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/collections/taking-control-of-your-catalog-page#how-do-i-reorder-products) and set the title to whatever you want.

Comment: Or if the link is the same across all pages, you could just set the title manually: `<a href="/collections/all">All Products</a>`

Comment: Might it be because I have not manually created a ALL COLLECTION collection.

Comment: @jewels I don't think so, `collections.all.title` returned "Products" before I created an "all" collection. Creating the collection just lets you change the title to something other than the default.

Comment: @jewels If it is a permanent link, why not hard code the `{{ collections.all.title }}` part to whatever text you require?